# Python Google App Engine Jinja2 Can't find Include

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm new to google app engine and python development and am trying to use Jinja2 as my templating engine.  I have a page that I'm trying to "include" a header and footer on and I keep getting this error: TemplateNotFound: base/header.html

My code is below.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

**Python**

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
   loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
   extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):


    def get(self):
        template_values = {'title' : 'Test Value'}
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/public/templates/index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

**Configuration**

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

**File Structure**

```
- my application
  - public
    - scripts
    - stylesheets
    - templates
      - base
        - header.html
        - footer.html
      - index.html
  - app.yaml
  - myapplication.py
```

**HTML (index.html)**

```
{% include "base/header.html" %}
<nav class="top-bar" style="">
  <!-- more html here -->
</nav>
{% include "base/footer.html" %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the loader property for jinja2 so i am not sure what this line does

```
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

But i do use App Engine successfully with jinja2 so i think i can help. I know by default jinja2 looks for a directory named "templates" in the root of you project. So for the header.html jinja2 would expect that file to be in "templates/base/header.html".

If you look in environment.py where the get_template function is for jinja2 if throws a

```
    If the template does not exist a :exc:`TemplateNotFound` exception is
    raised.
```

Create a templates directory in the root of your app engine project and move all jinja2 templates into there and let me know if that fixes it. When you pass the template names to jinja2 they will all be relative to the folder so call should look like

```
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
```

with index.html being in /templates/index.html in your root.

If it does i can show you how to customize the jinja2 default config by passing a dictionary to it.

Comment: If this does not work, let me know. I will provide a full example of my setup config with app engine and jinja2.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  I think I'm getting much closer based on your suggestions.  I changed the loader property now to this:
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates/', 'templates/base/') and moved templates to the root. I am now getting a new error: File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/loaders.py", line 169, in get_source
    contents = f.read().decode(self.encoding)
LookupError: unknown encoding: templates/base/ 

The encoding of those files is UTF-8.

Comment: That error is because of the second parameter in jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates/', 'templates/base/'). If you look at the source code for loaders.py, the constuctor takes in an encoding parameter as the second. So you are saying the encoding is 'tempaltes/base'. I think you should just remove that and keep jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates'). then reference your templates in base as 'base/mytemplate.html'. Let me know how that goes. If you want i will still provide my setup if we can not get yours to work.

Comment: I just noticed, if you were trying to give the loader multiple paths then pass an array to the first param. From their file. FileSystemLoader(['/path/to/templates', '/other/path'])

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  Seems to be working with: jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates')